# IDA - Rename Address/Function: Says name exists already but it does not show up anywhere

Tags: ida, address

I am trying to rename a function address in IDA (free) and it says that the name I picked already exists in the database (Error Code: 8727B0) ... but the provided name does not show in the functions window (filtered to check) or the names window (Shift+F4). The name is valid it's just "my_func" without quotes.

Is this normal behavior to say a name exists but does not? Is there a way to manually edit the IDA database file(s) to fix this issue. It should not be reporting invalid errors.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace in IDA database includes not only names in disassembly but also structs and enums, so check there too

Additionally, not all names are included in the name list (you can uncheck “include in name list” on rename). However, jumping to it using  G shortcut should work.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why it would not let me rename the address as the name I wanted did not exist any where else in the assembly. I should note that I when I loaded the IDA db back-up (i.e. prior to attempting the rename) it did print some error messages in the output saying "my_func does not have a back reference" but I had no idea what that meant and didn't see or think anything of it. I am not sure what the issue was but I just redid my disassembly in a separate file and kept the old IDA db as a "failed version".